Multithreading in ffmpeg with -f rawvideo
The newly released verion 7.0 of ffmpeg has greatly improved multithreading support for transcoding on the commandline. (https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#release_7.0) Previously transcoding with ffmpeg might have used 1 or 2 cores and capped out at 12%-25% of CPU. Now it uses 60%-70% of CPU, and completes the task much faster.
I've noticed that multithreading doesn't work when using the -f rawvideo switch, or perhaps I need to change my command line string to enable it?
for example: *
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -f rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt bgr24 out.dat uses only 12% of CPU but...
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 out.mp4 uses 60% of CPU.
Is there a way to make the -f rawvideo command use multithreading?
(* I realise the above example rawvideo command doesn't do anything useful, I include it only to easily demonstrate the difference in CPU usage)
Edit: I had a typo in the second command. Should have been out.mp4 not out.dat. Now corrected. Thanks to @rotem for spotting this.

Try perhaps the -threads parameter, placed just before the output file.

I tired a few values (0, 1, 2, 10, 24, etc) but it doesn't seem to make any difference to CPU usage.

It's perhaps not supported for rawvideo.

Add report to ffmpeg -i file.mp4 out.dat and share report.

@Gyan - how do I add a report?

Add -report ..

The command ffmpeg -i file.mp4 out.dat gives an error message "Unable to choose an output format for 'out.dat'". rawvideo can't be multithreaded because it is not encoded (uncompressed). The parts that my be multithreaded are the decoder, and the -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt bgr24. I assume that your disk storage is the bottleneck, since raw video is huge. For benchmarking without storing to disk, try: ffmpeg -an -i file.mp4 -c:v rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt bgr24 -f null /dev/null -benchmark. Also, please share the report.

Thanks Rotem. Yes - your command runs faster. Report for that is: https://pastebin.com/qf7J0R9e Report for ffmpeg -i file.mp4 out.mp4 is https://pastebin.com/5tNpaEvd (Note: I could only past the first part of the report as PasteBin has a length limit - but the rest of the logs are just repeating)
